# Deleting all files older than 2 days under specific directory names recursively

Tags: bash, ubuntu, find

I have written this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DAYSOLD="2"
users_dir="/users"
cd $users_dir
date >> cleanup.log;  du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr >> cleanup.log
find $users_dir -mtime +$DAYSOLD -type f -exec rm -v {} \;
```

I would like to delete files only under the "workspace" directory and older than 2 days.
How should this be done?

```
/users/user1/workspace
/users/user2/workspace
/users/user3/workspace
```

Thanks for helping. I would love to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-mtime "+$days"` selects files whose age (based on last modification time) rounded *down* to an integer number of days is *stricktly* greater than `$days`.

A file that is 2 days and 23 hours old would not be selected by `-mtime +2` because, it's considered to be 2 day old which is not greater than `2`.

So you need:

```
find "$users_dir"/*/workspace -mtime "+$(( DAYSOLD - 1 ))" -type f -delete
```

To delete files that are older than `$DAYSOLD` days¹ in any `workspace` directory² found in any subdirectory³ of `$users_dir`. Though you could also do:

```
find "$users_dir"/*/workspace '(' -mtime "$DAYSOLD" -o -mtime "+$DAYSOLD" ')' \
                   -type f -delete
```

Which deletes files whose age (in integer number of days) is either `$DAYSOLD` or greater than `$DAYSOLD`.

`-delete` is a non-standard extension, but is available in GNU `find` as found on Ubuntu and is safer and more efficient than using `-exec rm`. You can make it `-delete -print` if you want the list of files that have been successfully deleted.

Also remember to [quote your variables](/q/171346) and check the exit status of `cd` before carrying one: `(cd -P -- "$users_dir" && exec du...)` or `du` would run in the wrong directory if `cd` failed. Also note the use of a subshell or it wouldn't work properly if `$users_dir` was a relative path. It would actually make more sense to write it as:

```
cd -P -- "$users_dir" || exit
du ...
find . ...
```

(which would be more consistent if `$users_dir` was a symlink)

---

<sup>¹ strictly speaking, that's *at least `$DAYSOLD` days old* but considering that the comparison is done using nanosecond precision and that it takes several hundred nanoseconds to start `find`, that distinction is hardly relevant.</sup>

<sup>² strictly speaking, if `workspace` is a file that is not of type *directory*, that will still be passed to `find`, and if that file is older than `$DAYSOLD` days (and is a regular files for `-type f`), it will be deleted as well. You could switch to `zsh` and add `(/)` to the pattern to make sure only `workspace` files of type directory are considered. Do **not** just append `/` as you'd run into ³ below with more severe consequences (like when `/users/joe/workspace` is a symlink to `/bin` or `/`).</sup>

<sup>³ Note that symlinks are followed there. So if `/users/joe` is a symlink to `/` for instance, that will delete old files in the `/workspace` directory.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! May I know why you need quotes in "$users_dir"?

Comment: @TomS, that's the correct syntax in Bourne-like shells. See for instance [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: Thanks, good to know.

Answer (score 2):

try with this

```
find $users_dir/user*/workspace -mtime +$DAYSOLD -type f -exec echo rm -v {} \;
```

if it does what you're expecting drop the echo.
Consider adding -daystart if you want to consider the days as from midnight

Another easy way is using -path

```
find  $users_dir -path "$users_dir/user*/workspace/*" -mtime +$DAYSOLD -type f -exec echo rm -v {} \;
```

Comment: `-path "$users_dir/user*/workspace/*"` would also delete old files in `/users/user1/other/dir/workspace` (and the whole of `$users_dir` would be scanned).

Comment: your'e right.. it treats / as a matching pattern.. try with this 
find . \( -path "./user[^/]/workspace/*" -or -path "./user[^/][^/]/workspace/*" \) -type f -mtime $DAYSOLD -type f -exec echo rm -v {} \;